# Error 2503 y 2502 al instalar Workbench en windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, windows10

Estoy instalando workbench en windows 10 y da

> Internal Error 2503

y

> Internal Error 2502

al instalar.  A que se debe el error?  Cómo puedo solucionarlo?  Gracias.

Comment: El error es "Internal Error 2503" e "Internal Error 2502"

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente, es un error asociado a falla de permisos en los archivos TEMP por instalación/desinstalación interrumpida o abrupta, te recomendaría correr un clean en tu equipo, desinstalar y eliminar todos los archivos del Workbench , reiniciar e instalar de vuelta.

Comment: Lo hice pero no funcionó, quizás haya algún tipo de permiso que no me deja, mi perfil es de adm pero al ser una máquina del trabajo, quizás no deja instalarlo.